# Jquery clear textbox is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, textbox

I am using this function to clear my text box

`$('#txtcountry').val("");`

but it is not working there is no error in console also.
here is my textbox control:

```
<input class="form-control" 
  id="txtcountry" 
    placeholder="Choose your Country" 
      type="text" 
        onkeypress="return isAlphaNumeric(event);" 
          data-bind="value:ComonCountrySearchText, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" 
            required>
```

Comment: There is a `data-bind` attribute are you using `knockout Js` or something

Comment: Are you using some library/framework ? Becuase there is `data-bind` maybe the value gets updated from there.

Comment: Try setting value of `ComonCountrySearchText` to empty string and it should work

Comment: yes I am using knockout js

Comment: yes you are right @A.J i have to clear ComonCountrySearchText  first then it will work.

Comment: You're using Knockout, so just empty the observable, and I suspect the 'required' tag prevents you from emptying it?

Answer (score 4):

I have used the below code and its working find.

```
  $("#txtcountry").val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
 $('#txtcountry').attr("value", "");
```